# Plist file path error? path not returning a value

Tags: objective-c

i am trying to fetch the id matching a value in a txt box but i can't compare it to the value in a key

this is the path i am tryin to give

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@".lists" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the filename instead of ".list" in [pathForResource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/pathForResource%3aofType%3ainDirectory%3a).

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"plist"];
```

The '.' character before your file name might be the reason for your issue.

Comment: the name is .lists :S

Comment: why does it start with a dot is it a hidden file?

Comment: If you can try changing the filename, try it. I am not sure whether I will be able to access hidden files using this method.